# How to Loop Range number in Excel VBA without changing letter

Tags: vba, excel

How do I get this to work?
I have this code written so far:

```
Sub RemoveLoop()

Dim i As Long

For i = 6 To 15
If Range("B" + i) = "YES" Then
    Range("C" + i + ":" + "P" + i).ClearContents
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Instead of doing each individually like this:
This is what I'm trying to shorten/accomplish, below:

```
Sub Remove()

If Range("B6") = "YES" Then
    Range("C6:P6").ClearContents
End If
If Range("B7") = "YES" Then
    Range("C7:P7").ClearContents
End If
If Range("B8") = "YES" Then
    Range("C8:P8").ClearContents
End If
If Range("B9") = "YES" Then
    Range("C9:P9").ClearContents
End If
If Range("B10") = "YES" Then
    Range("C10:P10").ClearContents
End If
If Range("B11") = "YES" Then
    Range("C11:P11").ClearContents
End If
If Range("B12") = "YES" Then
    Range("C12:P12").ClearContents
End If
If Range("B13") = "YES" Then
    Range("C13:P13").ClearContents
End If
If Range("B14") = "YES" Then
    Range("C14:P14").ClearContents
End If
If Range("B15") = "YES" Then
    Range("C15:P15").ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

Simple question for you guys, thank you for your help. 
I don't know what else to say, it's pretty straight forwards I believe. But I'm still getting the, "Looks like your most is mostly code error."
This should be an easy one for you VBA experts to solve.

Thanks again.

Comment: Replace all the `+` with `&`

Comment: Also get into the practice of always setting the parent sheet to ***ALL*** range objects; `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range....`.  At least use the `ActiveSheet.Range...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
Sub RemoveLoop()

Dim i As Long
Set WSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' This enables the change in the mentioned sheet and not the Active sheet.
For i = 6 To 15
    If WSheet.Range("B" & i) = "YES" Then
        WSheet.Range("C" & i & ":P" & i).ClearContents
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You would probably get more up votes if you heeded the my second comment.

Comment: I used his code and just modified, for others I can edit the my solution. Thanks Scott. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do, passing the cells and the ranges as variables:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveLoop()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 6 To 15
        With Worksheets(1)
            If UCase(.Range("B" & i)) = "YES" Then
                .Range(.Cells(i, "C"), .Cells(i, "P")).ClearContents
            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Except for using `Range(Cells,Cells)`, the code is refering to `UCase`, which makes sure that "yes" and "YES" in column "B" are treaten equally.